# Sent a message to a number via twilio and got an errro 21610

Tags: twilio

Sent a message to a number via twilio and got an error 21610 - Attempt to send to unsubscribed recipient.

This number I have no record in our system of a Stop Message.
Is there a way to check a number before I send? I have a lot that were collected this way.

I also don't know if it matters or not, but this number was collected via a direct in person marketing. So they did not have an initiating text message.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio doesn't offer a way to check a number for unsubscribe before sending a message. Check history on Twilio console to see if the unsubscribe message was missed by your webhook.

**Solutions:**

1. When someone unsubscribes they pass the message to the webhook like a regular message. You might want to match the incoming message for unsubscribe keywords and build you own database.
2. For the unsubcribes missed by your incoming webhook, you might want to add the entry on receiving the 21610 error.

Comment: That is the thing. Out of 2+K from in person collection. I've only found a small hand full who have record in the twilio logs has having opted out before. The rest I can not find any record of a opt out on twilio's side or in our own held records. (Which are processed for opt out messages).